# How to have several interwoven enumerate environments?

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm looking to produce a document that has several `enumerate` environments with different headings interwoven, so that the end result looks something like this:
[image: the product of the given LaTeX]

However, I produced this by opening new `enumerate` environments every time I want to switch (the code is below), and as a result, the spacing is uneven (there is a greater gap between `A2` and `B1` than there is between `A1` and `A2`). Is there a better and/or easier way to do this? Ideally I'd like to be able to say something like

```
\item[A] Lorem ipsum...
\item[A] Ut purus...
\item[B] Curabitur...
```

My attempt at an example of what I need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{counta}
\newcounter{countb}
\newcounter{countc}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=A{\arabic*}]
\setcounter{enumi}{\value{counta}}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\item Ut purus elit vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae.
\setcounter{counta}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=B{\arabic*}]
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{countb}}
    \item Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    \item Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    \setcounter{countb}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label={A\arabic*}]
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{counta}}
    \item Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
    \setcounter{counta}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label={C\arabic*}]
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{countc}}
    \item Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas.
    \setcounter{countc}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=B{\arabic*}]
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{countb}}
    \item Mauris ut leo.
    \setcounter{countb}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `,partopsep=0pt` to each list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A BETTER WAY** using a newly defined `\Xitem`

Here, define `\Xitem` to take an optional list designator.  I also define the `Xenumerate` environment, which will reset the counters upon entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{countA}
\newcounter{countB}
\newcounter{countC}
\newcommand\Xitem[1][A]{\stepcounter{count#1}\item[#1\arabic{count#1}]}
\newenvironment{Xenumerate}{%
  \setcounter{countA}{0}%
  \setcounter{countB}{0}%
  \setcounter{countC}{0}%
  \begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{Xenumerate}
    \Xitem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    \Xitem Ut purus elit vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae.
    \Xitem[B] Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    \Xitem[B] Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    \Xitem Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
    \Xitem[C] Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas.
    \Xitem[C] Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas. 
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas. 
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas.
    \Xitem[B] Mauris ut leo.
\end{Xenumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL WAY** using the OP's basic approach

Adding `partopsep=0pt` to each list seems to get rid of the uneven spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{counta}
\newcounter{countb}
\newcounter{countc}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=A{\arabic*},partopsep=0pt]
\setcounter{enumi}{\value{counta}}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\item Ut purus elit vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae.
\setcounter{counta}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=B{\arabic*},partopsep=0pt]
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{countb}}
    \item Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    \item Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    \setcounter{countb}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label={A\arabic*},partopsep=0pt]
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{counta}}
    \item Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
    \setcounter{counta}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label={C\arabic*},partopsep=0pt]
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{countc}}
    \item Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas.
    \item Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas. 
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas. 
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesueda fames ac turpis egestas.
    \setcounter{countc}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=B{\arabic*},partopsep=0pt]
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{countb}}
    \item Mauris ut leo.
    \setcounter{countb}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks; is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw See edit, which I will fill in with explanation and image.